# BeautifulSoup XML: finding elements by sibling element's text

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

In the [following example](https://www2.hawaii.edu/~takebaya/cent110/xml_parse/xml_parse.html), I want to find all **titles** of books whose prices are 8.99. In other words, I want to find elements' text based on their sibling element's text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
XML = """<?xml version="1.0">
<library>
    <book>
        <title>The Cat in the Hat</title>
        <author>Dr. Seuss</author>
        <price>7.35</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Ender's Game</title>
        <author>Orson Scott Card</author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Prey</title>
        <author>Michael Crichton</author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
</library>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(XML, "xml")
```

Surprisingly, the query `soup.find({"price": 8.99}).parent` will return the wrong book:

```
<book>
<title>The Cat in the Hat</title>
<author>Dr. Seuss</author>
<price>7.35</price>
</book>
```

**Update**

The query `[x.parent.find("title").text for x in soup.find_all("price", text = 8.99)]` returns the list `["Ender's Game", "Prey"]` which is what I wanted. But is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find_previous_sibling()`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
XML = """<?xml version="1.0">
<library>
    <book>
        <title>The Cat in the Hat</title>
        <author>Dr. Seuss</author>
        <price>7.35</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Ender's Game</title>
        <author>Orson Scott Card</author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Prey</title>
        <author>Michael Crichton</author>
        <price>8.99</price>
    </book>
</library>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(XML, "xml")

prices = soup.find_all("price", text=8.99)
for price in prices:
    title = price.find_previous_sibling('title')
    print(title)

# and with list comprehension
titles = [price.find_previous_sibling('title').text for price in prices]                                                                                                                                                        
print(titles)
```

**Output**

```
<title>Ender's Game</title>
<title>Prey</title>

# List comprehension
["Ender's Game", 'Prey']
```